# Declaring JavaScript variable and then overwriting it multiple times

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if I am doing this in the most efficient way.

So I'm declaring my function `el` which is equal to a macro (Google Tag Manager), then I reassign or overwrite that previously-defined var which grabs the innerText/textContent of the element.  It then converts the string to lowerCase and then capitalizes the first letter of the string, before finally returning the 'cleaned-up' element.

```
   function() {
      var el = {{element}}
      el = (el.innerText || el.textContent);
      el = el.toLowerCase();
      el = el.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.slice(1);

      return el;

    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can using chaining, move the `toLowerCase()` to simplify a little and return the last statement directly:

```
function() {
      var el = {{element}};
      el = (el.innerText || el.textContent);
      return el.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

I'm personally not a fan of using a single variable for many purposes (I think it interferes with readability and maintainability) so I would probably do this:

```
function() {
      var el = {{element}};
      var text = (el.innerText || el.textContent);
      return text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Simplified a bit further by returning the last statement directly (one less line and assignment) and moved `.toLowerCase()` to operate on the final result.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have a valid concern about the repeated reassignment.

Based on the Single-Responsibility Principle, I would split this function into two: one that interfaces with the DOM, and another that transforms a string.

```
function content(element) {
    var el = {{ element }};
    return el.innerText || el.textContent;
}

function titleCase(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1).toLowerCase();
}

// The original function in question
function() {
    return titleCase(content(element));
}
```

Decomposing the problem that way addresses the code smell at the root cause.

Comment: Splitting functionality into 1 liners that you use only once usually fails code review. -1

Comment: @konijn Big assumption with "you'll only use once". `titleCase` and `content` look like they could be reused a lot assuming this application has more than one DOM element. Besides, these methods are now testable and composable which can be a big win.

Comment: Save possible upper-to-lower-to-upper conversion of the first character with `str.substr(1).toLowerCase()`.

Comment: @DavidHarkness The order of operations will make a negligible difference in performance, but I think that the parallelism of putting `toUpperCase()`/`toLowerCase()` last is appealing. I've incorporated the change into Rev 2.

Comment: content isn't a verb, functions do stuff - what does it do? `getConetentFromElement` or just `getContent`?